# Eigenvalues of a matrix that can be factorized as $(A+B)(A-B)$

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am investigating the spectra of a certain class of matrices $M$, whose eigenvalues, I strongly suspect, all have norm 1.

$$Mv=\lambda v \stackrel{?}{\implies} |\lambda|=1$$

I was able to factor $M$ as follows:
$$M=(A+B)(A-B)$$
where the eigenvalues of both $(A+B)$ and $(A-B)$ all have norm 1.

It is [not true in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/295569/89671) that the product of matrices with unit-norm eigenvalues has unit-norm eigenvalues.

**Example**
$$A=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right]$$
$$B=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right]$$
$A+B$ has eigenvalues $\{1,1\}$, $A-B$ has eigenvalues $\{\frac{1}{4} \left(3+i \sqrt{7}\right),\frac{1}{4} \left(3-i \sqrt{7}\right)\}$ (both of unit norm), and $(A+B)(A-B)$ has eigenvalues $\{(-1)^{1/3},-(-1)^{2/3}\}$. $A+B$ and $A-B$ do not commute.

> **Conjecture**
>
> Given two square (real) matrices $A,B$: if all eigenvalues of $A+B$ have unit norm, and all eigenvalues of $A-B$ have unit norm, then all eigenvalues of $(A+B)(A-B)$ have unit norm.

**Question**

Is this conjecture true? Any hints on how to prove it?

Comment: $A + B$ and $A - B$ can be any two matrices $M, N$, so if you know a counterexample for arbitrary matrices then you know a counterexample for this question. (We have $A = \frac{M + N}{2}$ and $B = \frac{M - N}{2}$.)

Comment: Do you also have that $[A,B] = AB-BA$ is zero?

Comment: @user7530 No. There don't seem to be any exploitable commutation relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example shows that the conjecture is false: For any $A$ and $B$ there exist $C$ and $D$ with $A=C+D$ and $B=C-D$.

Comment: Embarrassingly obvious in hindsight. So the eigenvalues of $(A+B)(A-B)$ have unit norm for some other reason...